# java websocket EOFException occur

Tags: java, exception, websocket, eofexception

I am using a Java websocket but I'm getting an error I don't understand.

When the server gets either a `RuntimeException` or `NullPointerException` etc., the `onError` method is called.

After that(finished onError method), the `onError` method is called again. After the second time, `EOFException` occurs continuously.

Do you have any idea why `EOFException` is occurring after `onError` method?

Here is my error log:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1267)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.isReadyForRead(NioEndpoint.java:1176)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:58)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:788)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1485)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Because the peer has closed the connection, almost certainly because of the prior error, which is what you should be investigating, not this one.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue that you did. If you use *NGINGX* to redirect websocket requests, you have to increase the `proxy_read_timeout` value. Otherwise, the connection will be closed after 60 seconds (by default).

Answer (score 1):

This happens usually when the client connection to the server is disconnected.
That can happen for a variety of reasons, often a timeout set on any load balancer that is in between or the tomcat settings, but it could also be the client and any network interruption in between client and server.

Don't forget to handle the exception in the OnError method, typically you want to close the session there.